# How do I click on an image change to other image and click to a video

Tags: javascript, video, processing

I'm having a problem on processing with keyPressed/mousePressed.

If for example I have some data file of Images apple, dog & cat, with two videos forest & garden.

The problem is I want to press a button and change to an image and when pressed again to change to a video.

For example start with

video = "forest.mp4" > keyPressed = UP > apple.jpg ;

with two selection of LEFT or RIGHT >

- if keyPressed = LEFT > dog.jpg
- if keyPressed = RIGHT > cat. jpg

both of them keyPressed = UP > video = "garden"

```
Movie myMovie[];
int index = 0;
boolean start = false;
float t0; //Movie Begin
float t; //current time

void setup(){
 size(1280,720);

img = new Image[2];
img = new Image(this, "apple.jpg");
img = new Image(this, "dog.jpg");
img = new Image(this, "cat.jpg");

myMovie = new Movie[3];
myMovie[0] = new Movie(this, "forest.mp4");
myMovie[1] = new Movie(this, "garden.mp4");
}
void draw(){
image (img, 0 ,0);
image(img, 0 ,height, img.height, img, height);

if (myMovie[index].read();
}

if (start){
 image(myMovie[index],0,0,width,height);
```

This is something like a old version of RPG game, adventure type of game.

While the player click on different selections would appear different results.

Comment: Very hard to read. Please post code and effort. I tried to format it a little but have a read of [mcve]

Comment: `PImage img;
Movie myMovie[ ];
int index = 0;
boolean start = false;

void setup(){
size (1280, 720)
im
img[3]

myMovie = new Movie[2];
myMovie[1] = new Movie(this, "forest.mp4");
myMovie[2] = new Movie(this, "garden.mp4");
}

`

Comment: Your comment is not useful. Please update the question with proper code and what you have tried

Comment: Besides, the title of your question is chaotic, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Store your state in a variable.

```
boolean showingMovie = true;
```

**Step 2:** In the `draw()` function, check that variable and draw the correct thing.

```
void draw(){
   if(showingMovie){
      //draw your movie
   }
   else{
      //draw your image
   }
}
```

**Step 3:** Change that variable in the `keyPressed()` or `mousePressed()` functions to switch which thing is showing.

```
void keyPressed(){
   showingMovie = !showingMovie;
}
```

You might have to have some logic for only reading the movie when the variable indicates that the movie is playing, and you might have to add some logic to only switch the variable when the mouse is clicked in the correct location, or the correct key is pressed. You also might have to have multiple variables if you have multiple movie/image combinations. If you have a lot of these, you might even use an array or a class to hold all your data.